# Find differences between many csv files

Tags: python, csv, compare

Currently I have around 3000 cvs files which I merge into one file. Each file has around 363 rows and 463 columns.

When trying to merge, I got an error like: "Error tokenizing data. C error"
I found a solution using error_bad_lines= False but I would like to know which file (s) are creating the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us your code so we can help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a try/except block in a for loop and add any bad files into a list that you can export.

```
list_bad_files = []
for csv in files:
    try:
        merge csv (without error_bad_lines = False)
    except:
        merge csv (with error_bad_lines = False)
        list_bad_files.append(csv)
```